# In Pygame i cannot make my sprite move?? is it my code?

Tags: python, events, 2d, pygame, sprite

my sprite doesnt move when i use the arrow key?? i have looked at my code and i cannot for the life of me work out what is wrong with it?? any help would be apreciated massively thanks in advance!!:D

```
    bif="cloud.jpg"
    mif="reddwarf.png"

import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

DISPLAYSURF=screen=pygame.display.set_mode((813,555),32,0)
background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

x,y=0,0
movex, movey=0,0

while True:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if event.type ==KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==K_LEFT:
            movex=-1
        elif event.key==KEY_RIGHT:
            movex=+1
        elif event.key==K_UP:
            movey=-1
        elif event.key==K_DOWN:
            movey=+1
    if event.type==KEYUP:
        if event.key==K_LEFT:
            movex=0
        elif event.key==KEY_RIGHT:
            movex=0
        elif event.key==K_UP:
            movey=0
        elif event.key==K_DOWN:
            movey=0

x+=movex
y+=movey

screen.blit(background,(0,0))
screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))

pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your indentation. It looks like your for loop which checks your events isn't inside your while loop, and neither is your code which moves your sprite or updates your screens.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your title first: If something doesn't work, chances are, that it really is due to your code ;)

Indendation is extremely important in Python. This part here:

```
x+=movex
y+=movey

screen.blit(background,(0,0))
screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))

pygame.display.update()
```

is outside the while loop!

Python works as follows:

```
while True:
    do_something()
    #this code will run while the condition remains true
do_something_else()
#code with this indendation level will run AFTER the while loop has finished.
#It's on the same indendation level like while.
```

You have to indend the part of your code I posted above so it is on the same indendation level as the

```
if event.type == ...
```

blocks. The way it is arranged now, the x+=movex ..... parts are waiting till the while loop ends - and that's not really ever going to happen, so there's no update of the x/y values and the blitting.

Comment: Thanks so much? As I'm sure you can tell I am new to pygame but I should have know this from my python experience:( thanks

Comment: Well, happens more often than you think :D Just yesterday I asked on here and somebody pointed out, that just the order of certain variables passed to a method was wrong, nothing actually with the code or the way I did it...

Comment: i now have another problem i am getting this error message:                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\reddwarf.py", line 25, in <module>
    elif event.key==KEY_RIGHT:
NameError: name 'KEY_RIGHT' is not defined

Comment: That's an easy one, no offense, but have a look at the block of code again... Ask me if you really can't figure it out, but I think comparing it to the if before and the two elif following it, should answer your question.

Comment: i genuinely think i am blind i can not spot it at all.. feeling pretty stupid right now haha..:/

Comment: It's a typo! :D
it should read K_RIGHT not KEY_RIGHT
And the same for the if event.type == KEYUP!

Comment: haha. thankyou feeling like a right idiot now hah. thansk it works now

Comment: Well, every then in a while we all act like one :p Happens to me as well.
Glad I could help you :)

Comment: 1 last thing my game does not have a box around(like the box that has the game title and the red cross)?? not sure why? haha man i really need to spend more time developing my coding skills

Comment: It might be connected to the way you call pygame.display.set_mode...
Mine just looks like this:

    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

I don't use flags nor depth as the standard values normally should fit. Change that part and read up on the display class in the PyGame doc.

Comment: thanks that has worked great. when making a game do i create my levels layers in pygame or in a seperate program? i have lots of questions but seems best to ask you guys as you have had everything correct thus far.:D

Comment: Follow the tutorials you used so far. At some point they will introduce you to how to use classes and their methods. From then on it will get clearer. It's hard at the beginning, but it gets easier once you get accustomed to the many ways you can do it. It took me about 1/2 year for the basics and now I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an indentation error.  You need to put your

```
x+=movex
y+=movey

screen.blit(background,(0,0))
screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))
```

In the     while True loop.